# Knockout custom binding doesn't update the computed function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a custom binding for an html editable field..

I changed it to use another custom binding now (HtmlValue), because EditableText had an error when updating the values (both custom bindings are included in the jsfiddle).

Anyone knows how to fix this?

This is the code that doesn't update the value:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlValue = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "keyup", function () {
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        var elementValue = element.innerHTML;
        if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
            modelValue(elementValue);

        }
        else { //handle non-observable one-way binding
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            if (allBindings['_ko_property_writers'] && allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].htmlValue) allBindings['_ko_property_writers'].htmlValue(elementValue);
        }
    }
                                 )
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || "";
    if (element.innerHTML !== value) {
        element.innerHTML = value;
    }
}
};
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/DMf8r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of problems with the way the view model is constructed and with the bindings themselves...

- The `tax_total` computed should be declared after `lines` because it accesses `lines` and Knockout executes `tax_total` as soon as the computed is created.
- `this` needs to be passed into the computed so that `this` inside the computed is the view model
- elem needs to be defined in the `$.each()` call
- To loop the underlying array in $.each(), you need to use `this.lines()` instead of `this.lines`
- The values inside lines need to be observables, otherwise the computed would not be notified of changes.
- The span is using a `value` binding, it should be `text`.

There might have been more problems but it's hard to keep track of what all the changes were...

```
this.lines = ko.observableArray([
    {  unit_price: ko.observable(5.0), tax_rate: ko.observable(21.00) },
    {  unit_price: ko.observable(5.0), tax_rate: ko.observable(21.00) }]);

this.add_line = function () {
    this.lines.push({ unit_price: ko.observable(5.0), tax_rate: ko.observable(21.00) });
}.bind(this);

this.tax_total = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0; //this.subtotal()
    $.each(this.lines(), function (index, elem) {
        total += (elem.unit_price() * (elem.tax_rate() / 100));
    });
    return total;
}, this);
```

---

```
<span data-bind="text: tax_total">1.02</span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DMf8r/1/

Comment: The values inside lines need to be observables, otherwise the computed would not be notified of changes is the problem i looked for, thx!